# How to switch display/non-display by right-clicking in C# of Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to toggle the visibility of the object with the following code.

However, when I right-clicked the first time, the object was hidden, but when I right-clicked the second time, the object was not displayed.

The object should appear on the second right click.

What's wrong with this code?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class EnvironmentSettings : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            Debug.Log(this.gameObject.activeSelf);
            if(this.gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                this.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable the game object that hold the script, it can't work anymore since it's not active!
That's why you can hide the object, but not wake it up.

Use a TargetGameObject field, that you'll enable/disable. Like this :

```
public class EnvironmentSettings : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject TargetGameObject;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
            TargetGameObject.SetActive(!TargetGameObject.activeSelf);
    }
}
```

Put this script on a GameManger, or at least something that won't be disabled during play time, such as the main camera. Then slide your TargetGameObject to toggle into the field from the scene view.